# .NET Web Application Async call working locally from VS workspace code, but not from server

Tags: .net, windows, api, asynchronous, webforms

I have written code to get data from an API. I am using an Async method to handle the call and processing of the retrieved data. The code is triggered by the user clicking a Login button on their Start page. While the Async method is running in the background, the user is redirected to another .NET web application page, their Homepage.

All of the code works perfectly when I build and run the website locally from VS, the data is returned and my code processes the data, adding it to various SQL tables.

```
myApiIntegration.Log($"GetDataFromAPI({querystring}, {displayInConsole}): Getting data from API")

Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await myApiRequest.GetResponse(querystring)

' only continue if request was successful, otherwise log an error
If Not response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
      myApiIntegration.Log("ERROR: API request failed: " & response.ReasonPhrase)
      Return Nothing
Else
      myApiIntegration.Log("API request successful")
...
```

I have checked my code in to a Test server. The site builds, and thanks to some logging I've put in, I can see that my code is triggered when the user clicks the Login button, right up to the API call itself: I can see the Request object is being initialised using the correct headers etc. The last log message I can see is created by the last line before the API call itself. The user is still redirected to their homepage.

After that, I cannot see any messages from my Async code. The next message I would expect to see would be either "API call successful" or "API call failed", depending on the response from the API (these are messages I'm logging from my code via Graylog, and again, they work locally); but there are no further messages, following the one telling me it is about to make the API call.

I have checked the server logs for errors. There are none at the time of logging in and running the API code.
I have asked our Infrastructure guy to checked the firewall for messages - he couldn't see any - but he couldn't see any when the request was sent out from my local code either (and this worked).
I have checked that my code is identical on my local workspace copy and on the server. It is.

Could anyone advise me what I should be looking at, what might be wrong, or what other avenues I could try? It's a Windows Server 2016 Datacenter VM. The application is a .NET Framework web app, written in VB.NET.

Comment: You didn't post any code so it's impossible to guess what's going on. What do you even mean by `async code`? What are you trying to call asynchronously? What does `not from server` mean? `async/await` is a language feature, it's not affected by the server or the OS.

Comment: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET MVC or Web API? .NET Old or .NET Corer? In web apps, requests are prorcesed by separate threads, so what does `async` mean here? Do you have an `async Task` or `async void` method ?

Comment: Async code - the code that is in the async/awaited methods.

Comment: Which means **what** ? `async/await` works. Post your code. Don't ask people to guess what's wrong. You haven't even posted what kind of application this is, or which stack is used. If you use `async/await` with WebForms I'd expect a lot more problems

Comment: It's a .Net Framework, WebForms app. Async means that my code is running in async methods, so that the user gets logged into their homepage while the code runs in the background. I mentioned the server OS because the code works on my local machine but not on the server, so perhaps the server OS is relevant, perhaps not.

Comment: **Edit the question and add the relevant information there**. You still haven't provided **any** information. Your description would match any web app, even a new project generated from a template without modifications. No, the OS isn't relevant, otherwise StackOverflow, an ASP.NET application wouldn't work. Neither would the hundreds of thousands of ASP.NET web apps.

Comment: Again, all web apps are asynchronous by nature - each request is processed by a separate thread. You don't need `async/await` to redirect to a login page and back. `async/await` is used to avoid blocking the processing thread while performing IO. WebForms was built 10 years before `async/await`, so it has limited support for it. So *what does your code actually do*? It's the *code* that does something wrong

Comment: Perhaps the code isn't awaiting what it should. Perhaps you use `async void` instead of `async Task`. Perhaps the only reason you thought the code worked locally is that only one request was made at a time, or that tests stopped before orphaned tasks threw exceptions. We can't guess what your code does

Comment: `While the Async method is running in the background` what background? Are you starting new threads or tasks  and forget to await them? This doesn't work in web applications. That's explained in [The dangers of implementing background tasks in ASP.NET](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/). When a request ends, ASP.NET disposes all the resources created by the request. [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-run-background-tasks-in-aspnet) explains how to do this properly

Comment: Thanks for the attention you are giving this, Panagiotis. I am relatively new to async/await but have written a few API calls that all have worked fine. Usually I have written them in C#. As I say, this one works from my local copy of the app, but not on the server. If the code is doing something wrong, why would it work 100% of the time from my workspace, but never from the server? That's what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: This has nothing to do with async/await. Read the links. The only reason it seemed to work locally is you stopped debugging before the garbage collector started and the errors were thrown. You **must** tell ASP.NET and IIS you have background jobs to prevent problems. You can do that with `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` in WebForms.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but in order to make an Awaited method call within a function, I am having to make that function itself Async - this is why I am referring to Async code and methods etc. My function is returning an Task of objects which contain the data returned by the API.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Panagiotis. I will read those links. When  you say "the only reason it seemed to work locally" I don't understand what you mean by "seemed to work" - it worked 100% locally, all of the data was returned by the API and processed by the remainder of my code.

Comment: It looks like HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem may be the solution I am looking for. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Fixed. The upshot is, the async method worked perfectly in my local workspace, but it needed to be queued as a "background work item" in order to run on the server. I used HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem to do this, after upgrading the framework to 4.5.2 because the older framework it was targeting did not support the QueueBackgroundWorkItem method. Again, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. My async method worked perfectly in my local workspace, but it needed to be queued as a "background work item" in order to run on the server. I used QueueBackgroundWorkItem to do this, after upgrading the framework to .NET 4.5.2 because HostingEnvironment in the older framework my web app was targeting did not support the QueueBackgroundWorkItem method.

```
                Dim ct As New System.Threading.CancellationToken
                Dim func As Func(Of System.Threading.CancellationToken, Task(Of MyObjects)) = Function() myApiIntegration.GetDataFromAPI(Int(idStr))
                HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(func)
```

Comment: `after upgrading`. 4.5.2 is the oldest supported .NET version. Even that is way too old, and 4.7.2 is the oldest version that avoids both TLS1.2 and .NET Standard compatibility issues

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis, I upgraded to the "least different" version which would enable me to do what I needed to do, but will keep your advice in mind for a future upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution for request-extrinsic code is to use a [durable queue with a background service](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html). While an in-memory work queue like `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` will operate correctly when everything is fine, it can lose work in the event of a server failure or rolling upgrades.

Comment: Thanks Steve. For this particular use-case it wouldn't matter if we "lost the work", but I'm mindful of your advice. We do have background services, run through Hangfire. But in this instance we are hoping to trigger some automated updates of our data through a user's login: if the site or task fails, the updates will be applied the next time they log in, or by Hangfire, whichever comes first.

Comment: Ah, yes; in that case, `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` (or `IHostedService` on .NET Core) is an appropriate solution.